# How to structure SQL regex to: find a string containing same beginning and ending but variable inner component; and replace with nothing

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have a Wordpress install with erroneous code present in the posts from an export. I can access the database and run SQL commands via PhpMyadmin.

I'd like to search for this code and replace it with just a `<br>` tag.

The code is structured like

```
[/vc_column_text][vc_column_text css=”.vc_custom_1553726355193{padding-top: 20px !important;}”]
```

`[/vc_column_text][vc_column_text css=”.vc_custom`_ and `{padding-top: 20px !important;}”]` are always the same. Only the numeric string changes, but it always 13 characters.

What would a SQL command look like that could accomplish this? Can I create a wildcard for just those 13 characters?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? You need 8.0 to get the `REGEXP_REPLACE()` function.

Comment: I am running 5.6.44-cll-lve - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Comment: `REGEXP_REPLACE(col, 'prefix(.*)suffix', '<br>')`

Comment: I haven't gotten this suggestion to work, even with a range of adjustments.